# Read param from web.xml in Ant build script

Tags: ant

I want to be able to build my webapp in several variants, using as few configuration parameters as possible. I want to be able to just specify the folder in relation to the root of the URL into which i want it to deploy (that is, if i want it to be at http://example.com/one/, i want to specify just the word "one" in my config file).

I don't want to have several web.xml files or several build targets. Also, I know that it is not possible to modify web.xml by ant without using some external scripts. In this respect,

Is it possible to read a parameter from my web.xml file from an Ant script and then use the value in building?

Comment: Do you mean to read a parameter while executing the ant script?

Comment: Yes, i want to read a param from web.xml while executing the ant script, and use this parameter in the build

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, that you can't modify web.xml without external scipts? You can update your web.xml values by simple replace task (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html). Or what is more common is to have some placeholder and use filtering on file copying (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/filter.html). Then you can specify filtered value as a build parameter for example, or read it from external build.properties file.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. If you make it as an Answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can read and modify any node/attribute from an XML file using XPath via the external xmltask :
http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/, http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/11/01/xml-manipulation-using-xmltask.html.

This widely-used ant task is very reliable.